# Let $R$ be a Discrete Valuation Ring with unique maximal ideal $M$. Show that $M^n/M^{n+1}$ is a vector space.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is a question from Dummit and Foote Chapter 16:

"Suppose $R$ is a Discrete Valuation Ring with unique maximal ideal $M$ and quotient $F=R/M$. For any $n\geq 0$, show that $M^n/M^{n+1}$ is a vector space over $F$ and that $\dim_F(M^n/M^{n+1})=1$."

I think this question should be straight-forward, but I am having a hard time picturing what $F=R/M$ looks like. In general, I am also wondering if I have to prove all 8 vector axioms, or if there is another way to approach this question.

Answer (score 1):

With the right level of abstraction, it takes only one axiom to define vector space:

> A vector space is an abelian group on which a field acts.

Let's check:
$M^n$ is an ideal, hence in particular an abelian group. $M^{n+1}$ is a subgroup thereof, hence $M^n/M^{n+1}$ is an abelian group.
$F$ is a field because $M$ is maximal.
$R$ acts on $M^n$ and $M^{n+1}$ (or any ideal) by left multiplication, hence also on $M^n/M^{n+1}$. Left multiplication by an element of $M$ takes $M^n$ to $M^{n+1}$, i.e., acts as $0$ on $M^n/M^{n+1}$. Thus we obtain an action of $F$, as desired.

---

The dimension claim is clear for $n=0$. Can you see how to do induction?

Comment: Thank you for this response, this really simplifies things! Could you provide a bit more of an explanation of where this axiom comes from? I understand how the first four vector space axioms are equivalent to the abelian group axioms, and the last four concern scalar multiplication, but I am not quite clear on what you mean by the field action.

Answer (score 0):

Pick some element $a$ of order $n$, then the map
$$m_x:R/\mathfrak{m}\to \mathfrak{m}^{n}/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}\qquad x\bmod \mathfrak{m}\mapsto ax\bmod \mathfrak{m}^n$$
is an $R$-isomorphism (thus an $R/\mathfrak{m}$-isomorphism).